# If $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb R$, show that the equation $(x^2+px+3q)(x^2+rx+q)(-x^2+sx+2q)=0$ has at least $2$ real roots.

Tags: polynomials, roots

If $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb R$, show that the equation $\\$
$\qquad (x^2+px+3q)(x^2+rx+q)(-x^2+sx+2q)=0$ $\\$
has at least $2$ real roots.

Is it possible to solve this equation without expanding ?$\\$
I thought of a way that maybe we can prove one amongst $(x^2+px+3q),(x^2+rx+q),(-x^2+sx+2q)$ has $2$ real roots, since these are quadratic equations maybe we can apply $D\ge0\Rightarrow b^2-4ac\ge0$, but I can't compare the $3$ equations I will get because we have no given relation between $p,q$ and $r$. $\\$
Any help will be appreciated. $\\$
Thank You

Comment: If $p=q=r=s=0$ then the only root is $x=0$. Did you mean counting multiplicities maybe?

Comment: If the question is correct, then prove that: $p,q,r,s\in\mathbb R$ doesn't exist, such that $$\begin{cases}p^2-4q<0\\r^2-4q<0\\ s^2+8q<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Aman The question doesn't mention that the roots are distinct.

Answer (score 4):

If $q=0$, then the roots are $0,-p,-r,s$. So the equation has at least 2 real roots. At least one of $p,r,s$ has to be non-zero if the 2 real roots have to be distinct.

If $q<0$, then $x^2+px+3q=0$ and $x^2+rx+q=0$ each have two real roots because their discriminants are positive.

If $q>0$, then $x^2-sx-q=0$ has two real roots because of the same reason.

Thus, in any case, the expression will have at least two real roots. If the roots have to be distinct, then the added condition that $p,q,r,s$ are not all zero is required.

Comment: If $p=0, q<0$, then we have at  least $2$ distinct real roots. Why  $prs≠0$?

Comment: @lonestudent I was trying to write something else. I've made the necessary edits.

Comment: Your answer still doesn't seem right to me.Let, $p=r=s=0, q<0$ then we have still at least  $2$ distinct real roots.

Comment: @lonestudent That is just one particular case. Here $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{R}$. We are supposed to prove that the statement holds for any value of $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{R}$. Without that condition, the statement won't be true $ \forall p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{R}$ because of the case $p=q=r=s=0$, where it is untrue. Note that I haven't used an "iff" but I only used "if".

Comment: You say, " Thus, in any case, the expression will have at least two real roots. **If** the roots have to be distinct, **then** the added condition that $p,r,s$ are not all zero is required." I say this is not correct. There are infinitely many counterexamples, such that $p=r=s=0,~ q<0$.

Comment: @lonestudent I've edited it to "$p,q,r,s$ are not all zero". I think it's fine now? Thank you very much.